# how to pass variable value in POST JSON data in CURL command?

Tags: bash, testing, curl, http-post

There are two fields which are unique , so i wrote a command to generate random value everytime the POST method is build and stored those values into the variables and pass those variables in the CURL command line. The script is below.

```
    rcontactno=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | fold -w 10 | head -n 1)
    rfirstname=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z' | fold -w 10 | head -n 
    echo $rcontactno and $rfirstname
    STATUS=$(curl -v -X POST -d '{"userName":"$rfirstname","contactNo":$rcontactno}' $1/restaurants/53/managers --header "Content-Type:application/json" --header "Accept:application/json" | grep HTTP | cut -d ' ' -f2 )
#Passing the URL using command-line argument    
if [[ STATUS -eq 201 ]]; then
    echo “Success”
    exit 0
    else
    echo “Failed”
    exit 127
    fi
```

then i execute the script by

> bash manager-post.sh

i get this type of error

```
  > POST /restaurants/53/managers HTTP/1.1
    > User-Agent: curl/7.37.1
    > Host: my-url
    > Content-Type:application/json
    > Accept:application/json
    > Content-Length: 54
    > 
    } [data not shown]
    * upload completely sent off: 54 out of 54 bytes
    < HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
    * Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
    < Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    < Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    < Date: Fri, 16 Jan 2015 08:59:01 GMT
    < Connection: close
    < 
    { [data not shown]
    * Closing connection 0
    “Failed”
```

but when i run the curl command without the bash script and explicitly mention the values of userName and contactNo , then it will execute successfully.

Where am i making mistake?

Comment: i run the bash script with the URL as a command line argument ! I have also try to mention the URL in the script itself but still output is the same !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quotes don't allow variable expansion in the shell, so you need to use double quotes instead. Then you need to subsequently escape the double-quotes you want to send as-is.

A useful debugging technique is to add `--trace-ascii dump.txt` to your command line and inspect dump.txt after invoking curl to see that it matches what you intended to send.